# Reinforcement Learning Agent in FMU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, fmi, pyfmi

I want to train a reinforcement learning agent on a model which i build in OpenModelica. By using pyFMI, it is no problem to import the FMU, simulate it, and get some results.

My problem is that i don´t have a possibility to "pause" a simulation after each step, getting the states, feeding my RL-agent with it and returning his proposed action as an input.

ModelicaGym seems to be a way to solve this problem by starting a simulation, stopping, getting the results, defining the next action and starting the simulation again with the last end-time as starting time.

Reading a paper from Lund University (https://portal.research.lu.se/portal/files/7201641/pyfmi_tech.pdf) made me think about an other idea:

Creating a FMU with the Learner, and connecting the two FMUs via PyFMI.Master.

Something along these lines:

```
from  pyfmi  import  load_fmu
from  pyfmi.master  import  Master

controller   = load_fmu("controller.fmu")
Circuit = load_fmu("circuit.fmu")

connections = [( Circuit ,"currentSensor1.i",controller ,"feedback1.u2"),
               (controller ,"PID.y",Circuit ,"signalVoltage1.v")]

models = [Circuit , controller]
master_simulator = Master(models , connections)
res = master_simulator.simulate(final_time =1)
```

Controlling the circuit with an other FMU with a PID controller inside works, but is it possible to create a FMU with a Reinforcement Learning Agent, including all other requiered Libraries, packages (Keras, Tensorflow?)

According to my point of view, such an implementation could have a pretty good performance, especially for models and learners with a higher complexity, this could be an interesting approach.

Or am I just chasing some dreams, because implementing a Reinforcement Learning algorithm in a FMU is not possible or causing other troubles?

Actually, i was a little surprised of not finding other people trying to implement this.

Best regards

Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be plentifully late, but nevertheless I found your question during my research for the exact same problem. Your question is - to my understanding - taken up in the paper

*Integration and Evaluation of Deep Reinforcement Learning Controller in a Building CoSimulation Environment*
[[PDF found here](http://www.ibpsa.org/proceedings/BSO2020/BSOV2020_Amrani.pdf)]

> However in our context, the co-simulation environment
> that is used for the study of Cyber-Physical Systems is a
> master of co-simulation, and need to be able to call AI based Python libraries or tools from within the co-simulation. In the co-simulation, the controller requires an
> interaction with the controlled component at each
> iteration. *Therefore, it is necessary to generate the AI based control components in the form of an FMU as is the
> case for the other components.*

They used a tool called DACCOSIM NG but later introduced their own methodology to make this approach more streamline.

Hope you long since found your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can update your question so it is more clear how the learning agent is implemented, but I understand that it can be used from Python?

The example [fmu_with_input_function.py](https://jmodelica.org/pyfmi/EXAMPLE_fmu_with_input_function.html) from the PyFMI documentation illustrates how to use a function as input an FMU. I suppose you can retrieve information from the FMU **in this function** like so (untested pseudo code):

```
from pyfmi import load_fmu

define input_object(model):
  response = model.get('response_variable_name')
  return ('input_var_name', learner(response))

model = load_fmu('model.fmu')

res = model.simulate(final_time=30, input=input_object(model))
```

You have to set up your model FMU so that the variables your learner should change (`input_var_name`), are **input variables** or **tunable parameters**. If you use parameters without `variability="tunable"`, you cannot change them in the course of the simulation.

I  would first try with input variables, because tunable parameters are a bit more complicated to treat and might not be implemented correctly in some tools.